# How to place a heart button with CSS

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to make an heart button, so I used a font-awesome icon,  but I'm having problems with the positioning of it. This is what I would like to be the heart button:

[image]

```css
.h_container{
    background-color: #cac7c7;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    display: inline;

}
#heart{
    font-size: 25px;
}
#heart:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Network</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3929e16ef5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'network/functions.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="h_container">
            <i id="heart" class="far fa-heart"></i>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the container should be an inline-block with exact width and height and also line-height (to set the proper vertical place of text) not an inline element.

```css
.h_container{
    background-color: #cac7c7;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    display: inline-block;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:45px;

}
#heart{
    font-size: 25px;
}
#heart:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Network</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3929e16ef5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'network/functions.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="h_container">
            <i id="heart" class="far fa-heart"></i>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok this works alone, but if I put this in my complete HTML file, it doesn't works. I insert a screenshot in the question to make you see. The <div class="h_container"> is inside of other 4 <div>

Comment: Ok I fixed, it toke the weight of the parent <div> , so now It works, thx